# Is there a way to return empty string intead of "\N" string for CSV formatting in old Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a query with `FORMAT CSV` that returns a string like this:

```
"2024-01-07 12:14:00",2.11,\N,\N,\N
```

As this is a CSV format I would like to see empty strings instead of "\N" strings:

```
"2024-01-07 12:14:00",2.11,,,
```

I know, that in the new CH versions, there is an option specifically for this - `format_csv_null_representation`.
Is that possible to achieve the same results in older clickhouse versions without `format_csv_null_representation` property?

The simplified query:

```
SELECT
    formattedTS,
    anyIf(toNullable(value), data_stream_id = 1) AS ds_1
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ts,
        formatDateTime(ts, '%F %T', 'UTC') AS formattedTS,
        data_stream_id,
        avgMerge(avgValue) AS value
    FROM reporting_minute
    WHERE data_stream_id IN (1)
    GROUP BY
        data_stream_id,
        ts
    ORDER BY
        ts DESC,
        data_stream_id ASC
)
GROUP BY
    ts,
    formattedTS
ORDER BY ts DESC
FORMAT CSV
```

All table columns are not Nullable.

Comment: Which is `toTypeName(value)`? why you try to use toNullable if your columns is not nullable?

Comment: Because without toNullable() I would get 0,0,0,0 instead of ,,,

Comment: i don't unsertand where you get 3,4,5 field if your query contains only two fields
and anyIf will return not null value

toNullable(0) always return 0
could you provide full query?